I suddenly get this error: 'You must install or update .NET to run this application' in Visual Studio
When I try to run my C# / .NET project, the console shows this error:

You must install or update .NET to run this application.
App: C:\Users\choij\OneDrive\
Framework: 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '8.0.0' (x64)
.NET location: C:\Users\choij\OneDrive\
No frameworks were found.

And this is what happens when I type C:\Users\choij>dotnet --list-runtimes on cmd:
C:\Users\choij>dotnet --list-runtimes

Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 8.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 8.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 8.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

I'm on Windows.
I think the visual studio has a wrong .NET location. I think it shouldn't be C:\Users\choij\OneDrive\
It's strange because the same project ran without errors a few minutes ago. I'm suddenly getting this error. I tried to research but couldn't find the same case.
I tried adding C:\Program Files\dotnet on the system PATH variable.
Result from dotnet --info:
C:\Users\choij>dotnet --info
.NET SDK:
 Version:           8.0.300
 Commit:            326f6e68b2
 Workload version:  8.0.300-manifests.4e5ea2d8
 MSBuild version:   17.10.4+10fbfbf2e

런타임 환경:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.22635
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.300\

설치된 .NET 워크로드:
 [maui-windows]
   설치 원본: VS 17.10.34928.147
   매니페스트 버전:    8.0.21/8.0.100
   매니페스트 경로:       C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk-manifests\8.0.100\microsoft.net.sdk.maui\8.0.21\WorkloadManifest.json
   설치 유형:        FileBased

 [maccatalyst]
   설치 원본: VS 17.10.34928.147
   매니페스트 버전:    17.2.8053/8.0.100
   매니페스트 경로:       C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk-manifests\8.0.100\microsoft.net.sdk.maccatalyst\17.2.8053\WorkloadManifest.json
   설치 유형:        FileBased

 [ios]
   설치 원본: VS 17.10.34928.147
   매니페스트 버전:    17.2.8053/8.0.100
   매니페스트 경로:       C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk-manifests\8.0.100\microsoft.net.sdk.ios\17.2.8053\WorkloadManifest.json
   설치 유형:        FileBased

 [android]
   설치 원본: VS 17.10.34928.147
   매니페스트 버전:    34.0.95/8.0.100
   매니페스트 경로:       C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk-manifests\8.0.100\microsoft.net.sdk.android\34.0.95\WorkloadManifest.json
   설치 유형:        FileBased


Host:
  Version:      8.0.5
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       087e15321b

.NET SDKs installed:
  8.0.300 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 8.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 8.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 8.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

Other architectures found:
  x86   [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet]
    registered at [HKLM\SOFTWARE\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x86\InstallLocation]

Environment variables:
  Not set

global.json file:
  Not found

Learn more:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/info

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/download

This is my .csproj file
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
        <BaseOutputPath>C:\Users\choij\OneDrive\바탕 화면\Turbulence_build</BaseOutputPath>
        <Configurations>Debug;Release</Configurations>
        <Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
        <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
        <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug'">
        <Optimize>false</Optimize>
        <DebugType>full</DebugType>
        <Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
        <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
        
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release'">
        <Optimize>true</Optimize>
        <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
        <CheckForOverflowUnderflow>false</CheckForOverflowUnderflow>
        <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
        <PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
        <ReadyToRun>true</ReadyToRun>
        <TieredCompilation>true</TieredCompilation>
        <Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
        <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <PublishAot>true</PublishAot>
    </PropertyGroup>


Can you [edit] in the output of dotnet --info? And when you run your application, what command do you use, and what is the current directory?

project file : C:\Users\choij\source\repos\Avalonche\Avalonche
using visual studio release run button
edited dotnet--info and .csproj file

now edited dotnet --info and csproj


I think the visual studio has a wrong .net location. I think it shouldn't be C:\Users\choij\OneDrive\

You're reading it wrong, that's not where .net is being looked for, that's where your application is run from.
You're running into OneDrive ghosting issues. Either disable it, or use a regular folder to host and build your application.

I'm sorry but what does regular folder mean?

"Regular folder" means "Not under OneDrive" in this case.

you mean baseoutputpath? or project file?

@MatthewWatson sry if you already read my comment but I wanted to ensure that you received the notification.

They mean that neither your project files location nor the build outputs should be on OneDrive.

In other words, don't use C:\Users for literally anything.

I changed the project file from C:\Users\choij\source\repos\Avalonche\Avalonche to C:\projects\source\repos\Avalonche but I still cannot run the project.

ahh the build output path was under onedrive. now I can run the program properly
